# free(): invalid next size in Python

Tags: python, numpy, memory, compiler-errors, kaggle

I'm getting the following error in Python:

```
*** Error in `/opt/conda/bin/python': free(): invalid next size (normal): 0x000055e1d43d2100 ***
```

I'm working in a Kaggle Jupyter Notebook, using extensively Numpy and coding in Python. The error pops up when I try to commit the notebook. To my understanding this is a C/C++ error linked to some memory issue.

Some of my guess are: a too big Numpy array is generated, np.copy() (that I use often) is causing some trouble or some memory leak. I'm able to run the code in my notebook, but committing I lose visibility of what input/outputs are and I have no control over the env/docker in which the notebook is run.

What is generating this error?